# Changing the display type of image to "block" rounded its lower corners, how?

Tags: html, css

I am not asking how to round corners of image. In given case when I mouse-hover on the image you can see that the image is not covering whole div as well as the lower corners are not rounded, but if I add `display: block` to the image, it covers the div and the lower corners seems to be rounded, I am unable to understand why this is happening?
See images for before and after `display:block`.

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="campus-col">
      <img src="./images/london.png" alt="london campus" />
      <div class="layer">
        <h3>LONDON</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.campus-col {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.campus-col img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block; /**** THIS PROPERTY ROUNDS THE LOWER CORNER *****/
}
.layer {
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.layer:hover {
  background: rgba(226, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

BEFORE `display:block` on mouse-hover the image is-

[image]

AFTER `display:block` on mouse-hover the image is -

[image]

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet - including an image. When I run it I get rounded corners at the bottom whether or not block is set so I can't debug your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have a look in your broswer's dev tools inspect facility to see what other stuff may be set in the CSS. For example, has a universal box-sizing property been set?

Comment: Thank you all, but I got the answer as pointed out above. The question is already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image . Sorry for the duplication.

Answer (score -3):

You can just write the following code instead of display: block;

```
opacity:1;
```

This will also work the same as display block. Just try this code and check wether again it is rounding the corners?

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. Also I want to know "Why" it is happening, and not any alternative ways of achieving it.

Comment: Hi, in order to ensure your answer is not downvoted you will need to make sure it answers the question - and the question is why is this happening, not ways of getting round it.